# Buildbot Git of a tag or SHA

Tags: git, buildbot

Is there a way to set the [buildbot Git](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#git) step to checkout a specific SHA number? The documentation says that a TAG can be specified, but I can't find any mention of specific SHA number (not that a format for TAG is any clearer. Just setting TAG name instead of a branch fails).

Comment: Commit ids are fixed, and tags are supposed to be static too. And if you think about it, it doesn’t really make much sense for a *continuous* integration system to only ever reference a single revision.

Comment: @poke: You have a point. However, the thing is that I have three Git repositories that I need to pull to get a build done. Two of them are not changing but the third one is. This question of for one of the non-changing two.

Comment: Is there a problem with using a branch for those that are not changing? Branches are cheap, so just create one for your purpose. But this actually sounds more like you should be using submodules, if one repository depends on two others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a *workaround*, not a direct solution.
In the factory, after the Git step to pull the master of the Git repository in question, add a `ShellCommand` step to basically change to the needed SHA/Tag:

```
fac.addStep(ShellCommand(name="GIT at SHA",
                        command=["git", "checkout", "76dd56c61ffa96b2cfe6b18e2fa7c054d8804508"], 
                        workdir="<GIT root>",
                        timeout=None))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a particular hash inside the revision property:

```
setProperty(f, 'revision', SHA-HASH)
f.addStep(git(name='pull.src', mode='full', repourl=src_url,
              method='fresh', alwaysUseLatest=True, retry = (60, 5),
              description='pull.src'))
```

Note, this won't work if you've already pulled from a repository, or you plan to pull another one afterwards. buildbot uses the got_revision property internally assuming if you've pulled one revision, you want to keep pulling the same one. In that case, you have to set/restore that property before/after your pull.